# Leave space if value not present BS4 python

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code to scrape data. Data are getting scraped. But the output is little messed up.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import csv
with open('ccccc.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for i in xrange(1,3):
        try:
            page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.codissia.com/member/members-directory/?mode=paging&Keyword=&Type=&pg={}".format(i))
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            continue
        else:
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), from_encoding=page.info().getparam('charset'))
            eachbox = soup.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile(r'members_box[12]')})
            for pair in zip(*[iter(eachbox)]*2):
                writer.writerow([text.strip() for item in pair for text in item.stripped_strings])
```

In the image that I have added you see that there is column mismatch.

This is the structure of the data that I am scraping

```
<div class="members_box_second">
                    <div class="members_box0">
                        <p>1</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="members_box1">
                        <p class="clear"><b>Name:</b><span>Mr.Jagadhesan.S</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Designation:</b><span>Proprietor</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>CODISSIA - Designation:</b><span>(Founder President, CODISSIA)</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Name of the Industry:</b><span>Govardhana Engineering Industries</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Specification:</b><span>LIFE</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Date of Admission:</b><span>19.12.1969</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="members_box2">
                        <p>Ukkadam South</p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Phone:</b><span>2320085, 2320067</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Email:</b><span><a href="mailto:jagadhesan@infognana.com">jagadhesan@infognana.com</a></span></p>                       
                    </div>
</div>
<div class="members_box">
                    <div class="members_box0">
                        <p>2</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="members_box1">
                        <p class="clear"><b>Name:</b><span>Mr.Somasundaram.A</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Designation:</b><span>Proprietor</span></p>

                        <p class="clear"><b>Name of the Industry:</b><span>Everest Engineering Works</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Specification:</b><span>LIFE</span></p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Date of Admission:</b><span>19.12.1969</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="members_box2">
                        <p>Alagar Nivas, 284 NSR Road</p>
                        <p class="clear"><b>Phone:</b><span>2435674</span></p>      
                        <h4>Factory Address</h4>
                        Coimbatore - 641 027
                        <p class="clear"><b>Phone:</b><span>2435674</span></p>
                    </div>
</div>
```

I want the data to be placed at the corresponding column. For example, all the names should fall in the same column name , like wise phone no and email and so on.. If Phone no is not present, it should leave a blank space on the csv file..
I am not even close to get the idea to achieve it.

[image: My Current Output]

Comment: Currently, what is filled if the value passed is empty?

Comment: the next coming data fills up the position, which I do not want to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based in what do you want I recommend you extract all the values sequentially and then write one by one. For example, look in the following code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import re
import csv

with open('ccccc.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for i in xrange(1,3):
      try:
         page = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.codissia.com/member/members-directory/?mode=paging&Keyword=&Type=&pg={}".format(i))
      except urllib2.HTTPError:
         continue
      else:
         soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), from_encoding=page.info().getparam('charset'))
         eachbox = soup.find_all('div', {'class':re.compile(r'members_box[12]')})
         for pair in zip(*[iter(eachbox)]*2):
            # I put only the most relevant, you can put more...
            dict = {'Name':'','Designation':'','Name of the Industry':'','Specification':'','Date of Admission':'','Phone':'', 'Email':''}
            for item in pair:

              #this is for the members_box1 , because all is organized by this tree                  
              for p in item.find_all('p'):
                 dict[p.b.text] = item.p.span.text

              # for the second members you need to use it equal but based in his HTML Tree, for example, of course in the second iteration :
              dict['Address'] = item.p.text


            # write to the CSV
            write.writerow([dict[key] for key dict.keys()])
```

In this way you can write the empty string if the element isn't present because you set in the dictionary the empty string and respect the order impost in the CSV.